# Browser plugin w3c validator?

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, w3c, validation

I'm using "HTML Validator" for google chrome, but sometimes it doesn't work, I want to know what is the best choice as a plugin to validate my local development site, the website is not available on the internet, and thus I need to validate the local html rendered by the browser...

UPDATE:
I've tried Kingsquare HTML validator as suggested by @vacation9 but I'm getting: 
UTF-8 decoding error of 1 bytes : 0xb4 = U+0180lx
line 113 column 297 - Warning: replacing invalid UTF-8 bytes (char. code U+00B4)

seems to be not working ok with my version of chrome(25.0.1364.97) running in ubuntu

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

[Kingsquare HTML validator](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/kingsquare-html-validator/anjdemaoejlpgmnmkijdemoiebcddhkc) is probably your best bet. Install it, reload Chrome, and then inspect element and go to HTML validator. This works offline and doesn't need W3C servers. It's a bit finicky however.

Answer (score 0):

HTML Validator works for local pages too... just use Cmd+Shift+A (on Mac).

Here are the shortcuts from the plugin homepage:

Windows/Linux:
Press Ctrl + Shift + V to validate a page
Press Ctrl + Shift + A to validate a local page

Mac: 
Press Cmd + Shift + V to validate a page
Press Cmd + Shift + A to validate a local page